# Google Charts Incontinuous Line

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I use line chart to show data from MySQL as below.

[Raw data from MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K6cI.jpg)

[Incontinuous Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BoD.jpg)

However, I got this incontinuous line. There is a gap in my chart. Does anyone know what attributes I set wrong?

```js
function drawStatusChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'N');
        data.addColumn('number', 'A');
        data.addColumn('number', 'R');
        data.addColumn('number', 'D');

        for (var i=0; i < chartData.length; i++){
            data.addRow([new Date(chartData[i].date),
                parseInt(chartData[i].N),
                parseInt(chartData[i].A),
                parseInt(chartData[i].R),
                parseInt(chartData[i].D)]);
        }

        var options = {
         width: 1200,
         height: 600,
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Status of Demo Unit'
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Device Count'
          },
          series: {
            1: {curveType: 'function'}
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_status'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: All your JavaScript Code seems ok and works with tested data you provided, but as a JSON Array. The problem may be when the data is fetched or queried from the MySQL tables as there may be data inconsistencies or errors for that row of data. You could try printing this on the console.log.

Comment: JSFiddle with JSON data: https://jsfiddle.net/tyx2nsp6/1/